# Setting VSTO CustomTaskPane DockPosition is slow in Office2013

Tags: ms-office, vsto, customtaskpane

I'm making an Excel Add-in which has a CustomTaskPane. On load I try to set the dockposition, height and width of the custom taskpane. Setting these properties executes almost immediately on Excel2010, but with Excel2013 it takes almost two seconds.

I've seen a [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f113c8a7-116f-4085-8e97-32f650b83706/excel-2013-setting-dock-position-for-custom-task-pane-causes-lag?forum=vsto) on MSDN about this, but no real answer was given. Are other people having this issue, and is there a workarround?

Answer (score -1):

Yes I do also have this problem. I think this has become an issue since Excel 2013 [is now SDI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/dn251093%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (Single Document Interface), which means each workbook has its own visibility states for the custom taskpanes that were application scoped up to Excel 2010.

**A Workaround to increase speed:**
It is still slower than Excel 2007 and Excel 2010, but you can disable the new Office 2013 animations in the registry to increase speed a lot, see [Disable Excel 2013 cell animation](https://superuser.com/questions/547832/disable-excel-2013-cell-animation).

Comment: This does not answer the question, and the link no longer works.  I observed this same problem in Excel 2013.  When I comment out the lines setting Width and DockPosition properties, things run 2-3x faster.  This may have something to do with Office animations, as suggested, but what does a developer do about it?

Comment: @OfficeAddinDev: Fixed no longer working link. I know that this is only a workaround, but there is no better solution I know, if you have to set the Width and DockPosition properties. So: The last question was. Is there a workaround - and I have posted a valid answered to this. No need to vote down...

Comment: The OP is looking for a programmatic solution, which this link does not address.  In testing I found that setting Application.ScreenUpdating = False before setting the Width and DockPosition properties can improve performance slightly (10-30% in my case).

Comment: Thanks for this tip!